# Firestore: Checking if a document field is equal to a value in SwiftUI

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I'm trying to check whether a Firestore document field is equal to "success" using the code below:

My listener for the Firestore document:

```
class ResultListener : ObservableObject {
@Published var results = [Result]()
private var db = Firestore.firestore()

func fetchData() {
    db.collection("results").whereField(kCONVERSATIONID, isEqualTo: Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
    guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
      print("No documents")
      return
    }
      
    self.results = documents.compactMap { queryDocumentSnapshot -> Result? in
      return try? queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: Result.self)
    }
  }
}
}
```

The function that fetches the data using RequestListener:

```
private func confirmPay(completion:@escaping (() -> Void)) {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 10) {
        self.resultListener.fetchData()
        completion()
    }
}
```

The function that checks whether the "status" field is equal to "success":

```
 private func showAlert() {
        if resultListener.results.first?.status == "success" {
        self.showingPaymentAlert.toggle()
        self.isAnimating = false
        self.createOrder()
    } else {
        self.showingPaymentError.toggle()
        self.isAnimating = false
    }
    }
```

The button that executes the functions:

```
Button(action: {
                    self.saveRequest()
                    self.isAnimating = true
                    confirmPay {
                        self.showAlert()
                    }
                       })
```

Although I can see from the console and Firestore that the field "status" is indeed "success", the function executes the `else` part instead of the `if` part.

What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: If the function is failing at "requestListener.results.first?.status == status", then requestListener.results.first?.status clearly does not equal "success".

Comment: Sure that's right, but I think it does not equal "success" because it is nil, not because it is another value like "failed". My thought is that requestListener.results.first?.status might not be a good way to use the data I fetched using RequestListener, might there be any other way to get the status value other than requestListener.results.first?.status?

Comment: Firebase functions are asynchronous code. I would recommend reading through the Firebase documentation (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) and watching some YouTube videos before moving forward.

Comment: @nicksarno, I made some changes to the code, would this make sure that the showAlert function starts after confirmPay is finished? Thank you.

Comment: I can't tell what's going on from this code - there are parts missing. I would add print() statements across every function and try to figure out why(resultListener.results.first?.status) is not equal to "success".